# How to duplicate and transpose VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My code blow, was made for only 3 years, (2016, 2017 & 2018). but now i have added 4 more years, but i dont know how to fit the description, so that i adds 4 more classes and four more on row Q Ark1. So that it fits with years 2016 to 2022. The code is added below, it transposes the information from Ark2 to Ark1.

I really hope you can help.

```
Sub TransposeAH()

    Const cSheet1 As Variant = "Ark2"   ' Sheet1 Name/Index
    Const cSheet2 As Variant = "Ark1"   ' Sheet2 Name/Index
    Const cFirst As Integer = 23       ' First Row Number
    Const cCol1First As Variant = "A"   ' Range1 First Column Letter/Number
    Const cCol1Last As Variant = "C"    ' Range1 Last Column Letter/Number
    Const cCol2First As Variant = "E"   ' Range2 First Column Letter/Number
    Const cCol2Last As Variant = "G"    ' Range2 Last Column Letter/Number
    Const cColumns As Integer = 1    ' Number of New Columns
    Const cFirstCell As String = "N1"   ' Target Range First Cell Address

    Dim vntH As Variant  ' Range2 Headers
    Dim vnt2 As Variant  ' Range2 Array
    Dim vnt3 As Variant  ' Range1 Temp Array (if value is "")
    Dim vnt1 As Variant  ' Range1 Array
    Dim vntT As Variant  ' Target Array
    Dim LastUR As Long   ' Last Used Row
    Dim i As Long        ' Arrays Row Counter
    Dim j As Integer     ' Arrays Column Counter
    Dim k As Long        ' Target Array Rows Counter
    Dim m As Integer     ' Range1 Temp Array Column Counter
   ' From Sheet1 to Arrays.
    With Worksheets(cSheet1)
     ' Calculate Last Used Row.
       With .Range(.Cells(cFirst, cCol1First), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCol2Last))
           If .Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) _
               Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
          LastUR = .Find("*", , , , , 2).Row
        End With
       ' Paste ranges into arrays.
        vnt1 = .Range(.Cells(cFirst, cCol1First), .Cells(LastUR, cCol1Last))
        vnt2 = .Range(.Cells(cFirst, cCol2First), .Cells(LastUR, cCol2Last))
        vntH = .Range(.Cells(cFirst - 1, cCol2First), _
                .Cells(cFirst - 1, cCol2Last))
    End With

    ' Resize Target Array.
    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vnt2) * UBound(vnt2, 2), _
            1 To cColumns + UBound(vnt1, 2))

    ' Write Range2 Array to Target Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vnt2)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vnt2, 2)
            k = k + 1
            vntT(k, 1) = vntH(1, j)
            vntT(k, 2) = vnt2(i, j)
        Next
    Next

    ' Resize Range1 Temp Array (if value is "")
    ReDim vnt3(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(vnt1, 2))
    ' Copy first line of Range1 Array to Range1 Temp Array.
    For m = 1 To UBound(vnt3, 2)
        vnt3(1, m) = vnt1(1, m)
    Next

    ' Write Range1 Array to Target Array.
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vnt1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vnt1, 2)
            k = k + 1
            For m = 1 To UBound(vnt2, 2)
                If vnt1(i, m) <> "" Then
                    If vnt1(i, m) <> vnt3(1, m) Then
                        vnt3(1, m) = vnt1(i, m)
                    End If
                End If
                vntT(k, m + cColumns) = vnt3(1, m)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ' Paste Target Array into Target Range resized
    ' from Target Range First Cell Address.
    With Worksheets(cSheet2).Range(cFirstCell)
        .Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
    End With


    End Sub
```

[image: Ark2]

[image: Ark1]

Comment: It seems that your code is pretty dynamic already. Have you tried changing the constants at the top? cCol2Last is now set to column G for instance. What if you change that to "K"?

Comment: It says "runtime error 9" script out of range @AlexdeJong

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: If vnt1(i, m) <> "" Then     @AlexdeJong

Comment: Have you only changed G into K? Or did you also change C into G? The dimensions of the first array are not big enough anymore compared to the second array. The number of columns in both ranges need to be the same.

Comment: ahh im an idiot! thank you @AlexdeJong